# Repository pattern error in db context when passing entities context

Tags: design-patterns, repository

i am new to repository pattern trying to implement from an example on below link

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/

Using database as entity framework from this site
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj614587.aspx

i get this error
[image]

Comment: You have not supplied the proper parameter (or parameters) to the UnitOfWork constructor.

Comment: and the proper parameter is?

Comment: Whatever parameter the constructor has defined -- that's in your code -- which you have not shared. If I were to guess, it would be that SchoolEntities does not inherit from the proper base class, or implement the proper interface.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. here is the code i am trying to learn http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/. i have also shared the database given in this example over here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj614587.aspx. Please help